# TextViews Gravity does not work center?

Tags: android, xml, layout, canvas, draw

when i draw the Drawing Cache of a TextView to Canvas, the Gravity of the TextView has no effect in center means not arrange in center it set left of the screen.

Here the class drawing the TextViews canvas to own canvas:

**code**

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(
                            getApplicationContext());

                    TextView textView = new TextView(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    textView.setText(str);
                    textView.setTextColor(myIntValue);
                    textView.setTypeface(tf);

                    textView.setTextSize(20);

                    // textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                    layout.addView(textView);
                    layout.measure(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
                    layout.layout(0, 0, c.getWidth() / 2, c.getWidth() / 2);

                    c.translate(weight/2, Height / 2);

                    layout.draw(c);
```

Comment: I think your TextView width may be wrap so please check width of you TextView.

Comment: have you tried setting the gravity for linearlayout i.e. layout instead of text ???

Comment: something like :  layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layout gravity.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams. MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of above code use this code. it will work perfect.

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
          lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
          LayoutParams lParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          mTxtView = new TextView(this); mTxtView.setId(R.id.name);
          mTxtView.setTextSize(20); mTxtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          mTxtView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA); mTxtView.setText("Country");
          lLayout.addView(mTxtView);
          setContentView(lLayout, lParams);
```